# Minimize quadratic function subject to linear equality constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, discrete-optimization

I am trying to minimize an equation which looks something like

$$X_{1}*D_{1} + X_{1}^2 * R_{1} + \dots + X_{n}*D_{n} + X_{n}^2 * R_{n} $$

constraints

$$X_{1} + X_{2}+ \dots + X_{n} = M $$

$$\forall i \in n \space R_{i} > 0, D_{i}>0$$

R and D is constant.

so when I solved this I get a formula for $X_{i}$ but the problem is when I solved it I get the values of $x_{1}, x_{2} \dots , x_{n}$ in decimal form.

For example for n = 3 and M = 10, I get values in form of $X_{1} = 6.8, X_{2} = 2.8, x_{3} = 0.4$ so I round them up and get final solution in the form $X_{1} = 7, X_{2} = 3, x_{3} = 0$ but is this an acceptable solution. (means is it right thing to do), because there can a solution possible where n = 3 and M = 10 and I get values of $X_{1} = 6.5, X_{2} = 3.5, x_{3} = 0$ when I round it i will get answer $X_{1} = 7, X_{2} = 4, x_{3} = 0$ now $X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3} = 11$ which contradicts the constraint(M=10).

How to handle this problem? (or this it is not possible to solve it by treating it as a minimization problem to get integer solution).

I want $X_{1}, X_{2}, \dots , X_{n}$ to be integer.

Idea 1:

I have noticed that the problem in my solution arrises only when there are mulitiple values of X with decimal value of .5 (ex 3.5, 7.5 etc) so I am thinking to iterate over all values of X and use ceil and floor function alternately when they have decimal value equal to .5 . I think this will solve the problem. (wrong)

Comment: yes all $R_{i} > 0 , D_{i} > 0$

Comment: R and D are rational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_id_i+{x_i}^2 r_i)$. $f$ is strictly convex and the constraint is linear. If there are no conditions about the $(x_i)$, then there is a sole critical point where $\min(f)$ is reached. If you assume that the $(x_i)$ are $\geq 0$, then the calculation is more complicated ( $\min(f)$ may be reached on the edge).

Step 1. It's easy to calculate $X=(X_i)=argmin(f)$ (if you are lazy, then you can use the Maple software "QPSolve" because $f$ is quadratic).

Step 2. Choose $s>0$ and  consider the box (centered in $X$) $U_s=\Pi_i [X_i-s,X_i+s]$ and you calculate $\min(f)$ over the finite set $\{x\in U_s|x_i\in\mathbb{Z}\}$; let the previous minimum be $f(\tilde{x})$ and let $f(\tilde{x})-f(X)=h_s>0$.

Step 3. Notice that, if $x\notin U_s$, then $f(x)-f(X)=\sum_i r_i(x_i-X_i)^2\geq \rho s^2$ where $\rho=\inf_i r_i$. Finally, if $\rho s^2>h_s$, then $\tilde{x}$ is the required solution.

If your first choice $s$ is not convenient, then choose a larger $s$; then $h_s$ decreases...

EDIT. A numerical example; implicitly, when I write $f(x)$, I assume that $\sum_i x_i=M$.

$f(x)=5.4x_1+0.4{x_1}^2+27.2x_2+0.3{x_2}^2+3.4x_3+0.2{x_3}^2$,

$M=102$. Thus $\rho=0.2$.

Then $X\approx(30.76923,4.6923077,66.53846),f(X)\approx 1790.792$

With $s=2$, $\tilde{x}=(31,5,66),f(\tilde{x})=1790.9,h_s\approx 0.1077$.

Finally $\rho s^2-h_s\approx 0.69>0$ and we are done.

Comment: I know I look naive but can you explain step 2 and 3 with an example.( prefere to take example from question) thank you.

Comment: or can you explain the process in detail.

Comment: can you refer to some link from where i can read about this method, I did not get how you get the value of rho and s.

Comment: There is no reference. I wrote the post for you. $\rho=\min(0.4,0.3,0.2)$. I chose $s=2$; if I found $\rho s^2-h_s<0$, then  I would have chosen in a second step a larger $s$; and so on.

Comment: I hope these are my last doubts: so for $f(x)=5.4x_1+0.4{x_1}^2+27.2x_2+0.3{x_2}^2+3.4x_3+0.2{x_3}^2$  $M=102$. Thus $\rho=0.2$ [this is fine as $\rho = min(0.4, 0.3, 0.2)$] and this $X\approx(30.76923,4.6923077,66.53846),f(X)\approx 1790.792$ I can get this from KKT method. $s=2$ is also fine but how did you get $\tilde{x}=(31,5,66)$ [doubt 1] because $\tilde{x} = ([28.76923, 32.76923], [2.6923077, 6.6923077], [64.53846,68.53846]) $ so from this how do you get $\tilde{x}=(31,5,66)$ because there are various numbers to choose like $\tilde{x}=(29,6,66)$ or $\tilde{x}=(31,4,67)$ etc.. continue

Comment: $f(\tilde{x})-f(X)=h_s$ is fine, but what do you mean by $x\notin U_s$ does this means when I choose a value which doesn't belong to $[X_i-s,X_i+s]$ this range.(that arises the question same as doubt 1 what is the method used to get $\tilde{x}$ ). now [doubt 2] $f(x)-f(X)=\sum_i r_i(x_i-X_i)^2$ why $D_i$ is ignored shouldn't it be like $f(x)-f(X)=\sum_i r_i(x_i-X_i)^2 + d_i (x_i - X_i)$.

Comment: [doubt 3] can you also please explain how can we claim that $f(x)-f(X)\geq \rho s^2$, especially this part ($\rho=\inf_i r_i$). last if $\rho s^2>h_s$, then $\tilde{x}$ is the required solution. [why doubt 4]

Comment: @anoop yadav , you did not understand one word of my post! (if you want do mathematics, then you must work). Doubt 1. $\tilde{x}$ realizes the minimum of $f$ on  the finite set $\{x\in U_s|x_i\in \mathbb{Z}\}$; you just have to link $n$ loops on the coordinates. Doubts 2,3. By Taylor for a quadratic function$f(x)=f(X)+1/2(x-X)^Tf''(X)(x-X)$ (because $f'(X)=0$). If $x\notin U_s$, then there is $p$ s.t. $|x_p-X_p|>s$ and $\sum_i r_i(x_i-X_i)^2>r_ps^2\geq \rho s^2$. Doubt 4. If $x\notin U_s$ and $\rho s^2>h_s$, then $f(x)>f(X)+h_s=f(\tilde{x})$, that is, $f(x)$ is too large!!

Comment: ok I have an another approach for the problem so after I get X = (30.76923,4.6923077,66.53846) from step 1, next thing what I will do is take floor value of all the elements in array and subtract it from their respective element (treating x as an array 1D) so now I have two arrays $A_1$ = [30, 4, 66] and $A_2$ = [0.76923, 0.6923077, 0.53846]. I know M = 102 so I sum $A_1$  I get 100 now 102-100 = 2 so now 2 elements from $A_2$ can be moved to their ceil value I sort the array $A_2$ and choose top 2 indexes to ceil rest all floor so now $A_2$ = [1, 1, 0] now add this to $A_1$ I get [31,5,66]

Comment: at the last step where we add two array there we need to consider elements are added to their respective indexes . What do you think of this method?

Comment: The simplest way. $y=[round(X_1),round(X_2)]:$ (you obtain $y=[31,5]$):m:=1790.792: for i from -2 to 2 do:for j from -2 to 2 do: $u:=f(y_1+i,y_2+j,M-y_1-i-y_2-j)$:if u<m then m:=u:fi:od:od:print(m);

Comment: CORRECTION. $y=[round(X_1),round(X_2)]$: (we obtain y=[31,5]):$r_1:=y_1:r_2:=y_2:m:=1790.792$: for i from -s to s do:for j from -s to s do: if $abs(i+j)\leq M$ then $u:=f(y1+i,y2+j,M−y1−i−y2−j)$ else u:=m:fi:if u<m then $r_1:=y_1+i:r_2:=y_2+j$:m:=u:fi:od:od:$print(r_1,r_2,m)$;

Answer (score 0):

Try Lagrange multipliers.

You will get $$D_i+2R_i\cdot X_i=\lambda \, \forall 1\le i\le n$$

Now you have $n+1$ equations with $n+1$ variables, so you can solve them to get the $X_i$s.

Comment: Yes i solved it using this method only but my problem is getting a integer solution of $X_{i}$ not  decimal